# Get average distance from a depth Rect image

Tags: ros, opencv, image, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get access to the average distance of some part of an image.

What i've done : Get image from ROS, conver to to OPENCV image, save depth image, crop the image using cv::Rect. So, i get the full depth image and the cropped one. When I access one pixel, like (240,320) i get the distance in meters. But now i need the distance from the rect image, and for this i'd like to get the average distance from all the pixels.

I tried to use cv::Scalar mean = cv::mean(ROI) passing the cropped image and then use mean[0], but it shows random numbers. I also tried mean.val[0]. '0' is because the others 3 channels is (i guess) for bgr and the image is grayscale.

Anyway, is there another way to get this average or am i doing it wrong ? I could do two loops for this problem, but i want to use opencv funtions.

Thank you!

EDIT [ code ]

```
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr Dest = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg);
  ROS_INFO("Distance from center: %f", Dest->image.at<float>(240,320));
  Dest->image.convertTo(depth16S, CV_16S, 30);
  cv::imwrite("Depth_image.png", depth16S);
//ROS_INFO("DEPTH_IMAGE SAVED");

ROI = depth16S(cv::Rect(140,220,200,200));
cv::Scalar mean = cv::mean(ROI);
ROS_INFO("MEAN: %f", mean.val[0]);
```

EDIT 2 [ solution ]

I realized that the distance information are in 'Dest' variable, not in depth16S. So, the solution is to crop the Dest and calculate the average using mean function.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186723/get-average-distance-from-a-depth-rect-image/) by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle what you've done should work. Did you create the ROI matrix something like:

```
cv::Mat roi( depth_image, cv::Rect( left, top, width, height ) );
```

Also you can apply the [] operator directly to the cv::Scalar like `mean[0]` (don't know if this makes any difference)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-07-16**:
Thank you for the answer! Can you please see my Edit ? Maybe i'm doing something wrong. I declared depth16S and ROI as a global cv::Mat variable. The first ROS_INFO shows me the distance (meters). The second gives me random numbers.